# Wrong result when using kiss_fftnd on 3D matrix?

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, fft, kissfft

I'm trying to use Kiss FFT on some 3D matrices, but my results do not match those I get when using Matlab. I was wondering if anyone could help me determine if I'm using the library wrong.

If doing fftn on the following 2x3x2 matrix in Matlab

```
    A2 =

   ans(:,:,1) =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6

   ans(:,:,2) =

   7    8    9
   10   11   12
```

I get this result

```
ans(:,:,1) =

   78.00000 +  0.0i   -6.0 +  3.46410i   -6.0 -  3.46410i
  -18.0 +  0.0i    0.0 +  0.0i    0.0 +  0.0i

ans(:,:,2) =

  -36    0    0
    0    0    0
```

When performing FFT using kiss_fftnd in I get this result (when formatting the result manually). Note the difference in the second row, second column.

```
78 + 0i  -6 + 0i        -12 + 6.9282i
0 + 0i   -12 -6.9282i   0 + 0i

-36    0    0
0      0    0
```

I use row major ordering when representing the matrix in C++, thus the input array is the following

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
```

This is the code I use to perform the FFT with Kiss FFT:

```
int ni = 2;
int nj = 3;
int nk = 2;

std::vector<double> values = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0 };
int *dims = new int[3];
dims[0] = ni;
dims[1] = nj;
dims[2] = nk;

int total = ni * nj * nk;

kiss_fftnd_cfg cfg = kiss_fftnd_alloc(dims, 3, false, NULL, NULL);
kiss_fft_cpx *in = new kiss_fft_cpx[total];
kiss_fft_cpx *out = new kiss_fft_cpx[total];

for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
    in[i].r = values[i];
    in[i].i = 0.0;
}

kiss_fftnd(cfg, in, out);
```

The output I get is the following (with added `i` to mark complex part):

```
[78 + 0i,  -6 + 0i,  -12 + 6.9282i, 0 + 0i, -12 + -6.9282i, 0 + 0i, -36 + 0i, 0 + 0i, 0 + 0i, 0 + 0i, 0 + 0i, 0 + 0i]
```

Am I doing something wrong when using the library? I would think Kiss FFT uses row major ordering (I have tried with column major ordering, but I still get wrong results compared to Matlab.)